# Issue with array replace

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

We have 2 arrays and we want to replace the values from the second array to the first array, it goes well, except one key it's duplicating..

The arrays:

Array 1

```
    [
        {
            "1": 0
        },
        {
            "2": 0
        },
        {
            "3": 0
        },
        {
            "4": 0
        },
        {
            "5": 0
        },
        {
            "6": 0
        },
        {
            "7": 0
        },
        {
            "8": 0
        },
        {
            "9": 0
        },
        {
            "10": 0
        },
        {
            "11": 0
        },
        {
            "12": 0
        }
    ]
```

Array 2

```
   [
            {
                "2": 4526
            },
            {
                "3": 81
            },
            {
                "4": 20
            }
        ]
```

we proceed with

```
array_replace($array1, $array2);
```

It should return updates on the values with the key 2, 3 and 4 - however we receive this result:

```
[
    [
        {
            "2": 4526
        },
        {
            "3": 81
        },
        {
            "4": 20
        },
        {
            "4": 0
        },
        {
            "5": 0
        },
        {
            "6": 0
        },
        {
            "7": 0
        },
        {
            "8": 0
        },
        {
            "9": 0
        },
        {
            "10": 0
        },
        {
            "11": 0
        },
        {
            "12": 0
        }
    ]
]
```

There duplicate of key with number 4, and the key with number 1 is missing at all.

Any advice please?

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, verified example in code that we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure "1", "2" ... are the keys of your array?

Comment: This is not what you would call an actual “duplicate key” to begin with. You have _different_ objects here, and inside each the key is of course unique, not least because it could not technically be otherwise. They keys array_replace is looking at here, are the keys of your outer arrays - which you did not explicitly specify, so they are simply numeric, zero-based. `{"1": 0}` is the element with key 0 in your first array, and it gets replaced with what the second array had under that same key, which is `{"2": 4526}` … works as designed.